как получить access_token пользователя с https://vkhost.github.io,используя python?
Имеется вот такой скрипт,который должен получать токен пользователя по vkhost.github.io,возможно ли это реализовать?
Update: Когда пользователь переходит в бота и пишет команду /token или /my_token,ему бот должен дать именно его access_token. Поясняю,бот должен парсить токен пользователя,и выдавать уже токен ему!
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.types import Message
import time
import requests

bot = Bot(token="YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(msg: Message):
    await msg.reply('Приветствую тебя, {}!\nЯ помогу тебе получить твой access_token от площадки ВКонтакте, не заходя на сайт https://vkhost.github.io'.format(msg.from_user.first_name))


@dp.message_handler(commands=['token', 'my_token'])
async def get_token_vk(msg: Message):
    try:
        get_token = requests.get('https://vkhost.github.io')
        await msg.reply(' Получаю ваш access_token...nn⚠️ Внимание: Данная процедура никак не повредит вашей странице ВКонтакте.')
        time.sleep(3)  # Пауза для эмуляции получения токена (можно убрать)
        
        # Логика получения access_token пользователя ВКонтакте

        access_token = get_token.json()  # Получение данных JSON из ответа
        await msg.reply(" Ваш токен пользователя: {}\n Пожалуйста, в целях безопасности не передавайте его никому.".format(access_token))
    except Exception as e:
        print('ОШИБКА:', e)
        await msg.reply('⚠️ Произошла ошибка при получении access_token. Попробуйте позже.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
